# Solution Check - Solving complicated summation limit and understanding ratio test.

Tags: limits, solution-verification, summation

I have the following limit

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n \left( \left( a_k \prod_{i=k+1}^{n} b_i \right) - c_k \right) $$

It's a bit ugly, but I know that $2 < c_k < a_k$ and $0 < b_k < 1$ for all k. Written out, this looks something like

$$
\begin{align}
a_1 \cdot b_2 \cdot b_3 \cdot \dots\cdot  b_n - c_1 + \ \\
a_2 \cdot b_3 \cdot \dots \cdot b_n - c_2 + \ \\
\dots + \ \\
a_{n-1} \cdot b_n - c_{n-1} + \ \\
a_n - c_n \ \ \ \ \
\end{align}$$

I've been kinda stuck on this for a while, this is my latest attempt, and I'd really appreciate being called out on any mistakes I make.

From the information given, it seems clear that

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \prod_{i=k+1}^{n} b_i \to 0$$

because $b_i < 1$ so I'm multiplying decimals infinitely. Which means that each subsequent multiplication must get closer and closer to 0. Because I'm taking $n \to \infty$, it doesn't really matter what the starting index is either because there will always be infinitely more ahead of it.

Next, I think it's also clear that because $2 < c_k$ for all $k$, that we can say

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n c_k > \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n 2 = \lim_{n \to \infty} 2n \to \infty$$.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{k=1}^n c_k \to \infty$$

But if we look at the ratio test of this sum. We get

$$\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_k} = L$$

And because we know that this sum is divergent, then $L > 1$.

Now, finally, if we look at the original sum, if we do the ratio test of it, we get

$$\frac{a_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} - c_{k+1}}{a_{k} \cdot b_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} - c_{k}} = M$$

And now we want to know if $M > 1$ or if $M = 1$ or if $M < 1$. That will tell us the convergence of this. So let's multiply by the denominator

$${a_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} - c_{k+1}} = M({a_{k} \cdot b_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} - c_{k}})$$

Distribute

$${a_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} - c_{k+1}} = M \cdot {a_{k} \cdot b_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} - M \cdot c_{k}}$$

Rearranging slightly gives us

$${a_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} - M \cdot {a_{k} \cdot b_{k+1} \cdot b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n} = c_{k+1}} - M \cdot c_{k}}$$

And now let's pull out all of the $b$ terms.

$$(b_{k+2} \cdot b_{k+3} \cdot \dots \cdot b_{n}) \cdot ({a_{k+1} - M \cdot {a_{k} \cdot b_{k+1} ) = c_{k+1}} - M \cdot c_{k}}$$

Or in other words

$$\prod_{i=k+2}^{n} b_i \cdot ({a_{k+1} - M \cdot {a_{k} \cdot b_{k+1} ) = c_{k+1}} - M \cdot c_{k}}$$

Now this is a sketchy part because I don't know if the limit is applicable in the ratio test, but it seems like it would be safe to say that we're still considering the limit as $n \to \infty$. Then this becomes

$$0 \cdot ({a_{k+1} - M \cdot {a_{k} \cdot b_{k+1} ) = c_{k+1}} - M \cdot c_{k}}$$

Or in other words

$$0 = c_{k+1} - M \cdot c_{k}$$

And now solving for $M$ gives us

$$\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_{k}} = M$$

But we already know from before that when we had $\frac{c_{k+1}}{c_{k}} = L$ that $L > 1$, so then that means that it must be that $M > 1$. And thus the original sum is divergent.

Did I do all this correctly? If not, where did I screw up?

I'd sure appreciate feedback even if there are no mistakes just so that I know that I didn't mess up.

Thanks all